# Getting Error During Posting data :The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am uploading a excel data to grid and sending data to server for saving by ajax call but unfortunately getting this error and can't resolved.

I understood this error and had many tried to resolved but no luck

I don't know if i receiving this much data from the server,so why not send to server?

It would be appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Thanks in Advance !

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <!--<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" />-->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>


   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

Error:

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input


   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger value? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Comment: @sam yes I have tried that one also but no luck.